# Is there an easy way to use prototype show hide functions on array of html elements

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I noticed that you can't use the `show` function on an array of html elements like the list of elements returned when you apply a `document.getELementsByClassName` call. For which I have to make a little loop and apply the `show/hide` or any other extended dom function to the individual elements.

If there an easy way to do this in prototype without having to go through a loop? Just asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try [invoke](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/enumerable/prototype/invoke/)

```
myArray.invoke('show');
```

Or you can use [each](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/enumerable/prototype/each/)